# How do I place a pixel on the screen in BBC BASIC?

Tags: pixel, basic, bbc-micro

I have attempted using scripts from other BASIC resources on the internet, but they yield an error message.

Comment: You might try https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com as they focus on very old systems and ROM BASICs like BBC.  Your chances of a good answer are much better there than here.

Comment: A better question might be to put your best guess as to the appropriate method here along with the error message and ask what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the implementation, you can use PLOT 69,x,y or POINT x,y.